# Java - Searching for Separation Char

Tags: string, search, char, character, identifier

I am righting a program to help me track my mileage for work. I only travel to specific locations. I made a switch that has all of the possibly start and end locations I could have, along with their distance. right now when I run my program, a window pops up asking were I went for every location. I have to type the end location as the next start location every time. I want to be able to type out one long string (ex: location1>location2+location3>location4) and have it calculate the total mileage.

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] agrs) {
        double total = 0;
        double d = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int t = 0;
        //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        // String place;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "MILEAGE CALCULATOR \n\nLocations: ADMIN, AE, BE, CE, CHS, CJHS, IE, NSE, PKE, RHS, SMS, SPE \nFormat: Location1>Location2");
    //  JOptionPane.showMessagedialog(null,"Locations: ADMIN, AE, BE, CE, CHS, CJHS, IE, NSE, PKE, RHS, SMS, SPE");

        //System.out.println("MILAGE CALCULATOR \nLocations: ADMIN, AE, BE, CE, CHS, CJHS, IE, NSE, PKE, RHS, SMS, SPE \nFormat: LOCATION1>LOCATION2");
        t = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many places did you go to from the admin building?"));
        //t = input.nextInt();
        //t++;

        // System.out.println(t);
        // System.out.println(c);
        while (t > c) {
            String place = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "where did you go?");
            //String place = input.nextLine();
        //  place.equalsIgnoreCase(place);
            d=0;
            switch (place.toUpperCase()) {
            case "ADMIN>AE":
            case "AE>ADMIN":
                d = 7;
                break;
            case "ADMIN>BE":
            case "BE>ADMIN":
                d = 2.8;
                break;
            case "ADMIN>CE":
            case "CE>ADMIN":
                d = 1.5;
                break;
            case "ADMIN>CHS":
            case "CHS>ADMIN":
                d = .6;
                break;
            case "ADMIN>CJHS":
            case "CJHS>ADMIN":
                d = 1.5;
                break;
            case "ADMIN>IE":
            case "IE>ADMIN":
                d = 2.3;
                break;
            case "ADMIN>NSE":
            case "NSE>ADMIN":
                d = 4.5;
                break;
            case "ADMIN>PKE":
            case "PKE>ADMIN":
                d = 2.6;
                break;
            case "ADMIN>RHS":
            case "RHS>ADMIN":
                d = 1.5;
                break;
            case "ADMIN>SMS":
            case "SMS>ADMIN":
                d = 3.9;
                break;
            case "ADMIN>SPE":
            case "SPE>ADMIN":
                d = 3.2;
                break;
            case "AE>BE":
            case "BE>AE":
                d = 9.5;
                break;
            case "AE>CE":
            case "CE>AE":
                d = 6.3;
                break;
            case "AE>CHS":
            case "CHS>AE":
                d = 7.6;
                break;
            case "AE>CJHS":
            case "CJHS>AE":
                d = 6.3;
                break;
            case "AE>IE":
            case "IE>AE":
                d = 6.3;
                break;
            case "AE>NSE":
            case "NSE>AE":
                d = 8;
                break;
            case "AE>PKE":
            case "PKE>AE":
                d = 7.6;
                break;
            case "AE>RHS":
            case "RHS>AE":
                d = 6.3;
                break;
            case "AE>SMS":
            case "SMS>AE":
                d = 8.2;
                break;
            case "AE>SPE":
            case "SPE>AE":
                d = 7.5;
                break;
            case "BE>CE":
            case "CE>BE":
                d = 3.7;
                break;
            case "BE>CHS":
            case "CHS>BE":
                d = 2.7;
                break;
            case "BE>CJHS":
            case "CJHS>BE":
                d = 3.7;
                break;
            case"BE>IE":
            case "IE>BE":
                d = 5;
                break;
            case "BE>NSE":
            case "NSE>BE":
                d = 4.2;
                break;
            case "BE>PKE":
            case "PKE>BE":
                d = 2.8;
                break;
            case "BE>RHS":
            case "RHS>BE":
                d = 3.7;
                break;
            case "BE>SMS":
            case "SMS>BE":
                d = 4.2;
                break;
            case "BE>SPE":
            case "SPE>BE":
                d = 7.4;
                break;
            case "CE>CHS":
            case "CHS>CE":
                d = 1.9;
                break;
            case "CE>CJHS":
            case "CJHS>CE":
                d = 0;
                break;
            case "CE>IE":
            case "IE>CE":
                d = 2.5;
                break;
            case "CE>NSE":
            case "NSE>CE":
                d = 3.5;
                break;
            case "CE>PKE":
            case "PKE>CE":
                d = 2.3;
                break;
            case "CE>RHS":
            case "RHS>CE":
                d = 0;
                break;
            case "CE>SMS":
            case "SMS>CE":
                d = 3.7;
                break;
            case "CE>SPE":
            case "SPE>CE":
                d = 3.3;
                break;
            case "CHS>CJHS":
            case "CJHS>CHS":
                d = 1.8;
                break;
            case "CHS>IE":
            case "IE>CHS":
                d = 2.9;
                break;
            case "CHS>NSE":
            case "NSE>CHS":
                d = 3.2;
                break;
            case "CHS>PKE":
            case "PKE>CHS":
                d = 2;
                break;
            case "CHS>RHS":
            case "RHS>CHS":
                d = 1.9;
                break;
            case "CHS>SMS":
            case "SMS>CHS":
                d = 3.3;
                break;
            case "CHS>SPE":
            case "SPE>CHS":
                d = 3.8;
                break;
            case "CJHS>IE":
            case "IE>CJHS":
                d = 2.5;
                break;
            case "CJHS>NSE":
            case "NSE>CJHS":
                d = 4.3;
                break;
            case "CJHS>PKE":
            case "PKE>CJHS":
                d = 2.3;
                break;
            case "CJHS>RHS":
            case "RHS>CJHS":
                d = 0;
                break;
            case "CJHS>SMS":
            case "SMS>CJHS":
                d = 3.7;
                break;
            case "CJHS>SPE":
            case "SPE>CJHS":
                d = 3.3;
                break;
            case "IE>NSE":
            case "NSE>IE":
                d = 5.8;
                break;
            case "IE>PKE":
            case "PKE>IE":
                d = 4.6;
                break;
            case "IE>RHS":
            case "RHS>IE":
                d = 2.5;
                break;
            case "IE>SMS":
            case "SMS>IE":
                d = 6;
                break;
            case "IE>SPE":
            case "SPE>IE":
                d = 3.1;
                break;
            case "NSE>PKE":
            case "PKE>NSE":
                d = 1.3;
                break;
            case "NSE>RHS":
            case "RHS>NSE":
                d = 3.5;
                break;
            case "NSE>SMS":
            case "SMS>NSE":
                d = .2;
            break;
            case "NSE>SPE":
            case "SPE>NSE":
                d = 7.2;
                break;
            case "PKE>RHS":
            case "RHS>PKE":
                d = 2.2;
                break;
            case "PKE>SMS":
            case "SMS>PKE":
                d = 1.5;
                break;
            case "PKE>SPE":
            case "SPE>PKE":
                d = 5.5;
                break;
            case "RHS>SMS":
            case "SMS>RHS":
                d = 3.7;
                break;
            case "RHS>SPE":
            case "SPE>RHS":
                d = 3.3;
                break;
            case "SMS>SPE":
            case "SPE>SMS":
                d = 7.4;
                break;
            }

            // System.out.println(total);
            total = d + total;
            // System.out.println(total);
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("miles Driven ", d+total);
            c++;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Miles Driven: " + total);
        //System.out.println(total);

    }
}

Comment: If you entered something like "location1>location2>location3" you could split on the > characters and process it in a loop by getting the element after the current one. You know to stop when you can't find a next element.

Comment: @jaimerump I think that was his actual question. How to find that delimiter character and split there.

Comment: @jaimerum, thats what i want to do, but i do not know how.

Comment: Oh, I thought the question was about an algorithm to use rather than how to implement it in the language. I've posted an answer that should help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
int total = 0;
String[] places = place.split(">"); //Split your input string place into a list 
for(int i = 0; i < places.length - 1; i++){
    String leg = places[i] + ">" + places[i+1]; //Create string representing this leg of the journey

    //Figure out the length of this leg of the journey using your switch statement

    total += d; //d is the variable you were using in the switch

}
```

So if you entered "AE>Admin>BE>CJHS" the first iteration of the loop would set case to AE>Admin, and use your switch to set distance to 7 and total to 7, second time through should get Admin>BE, distance = 2.8 and total = 9.8, third iteration BE>CJHS, distance = 3.7 and total = 13.5 if I'm doing my mental math correctly. Then i would be incremented to 3, and since the length of the array is only 4, it would kick out of the loop.

If you wish to format your string differently, here's the java documentation for the string class and it's split method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: did you mean to put "String[] places = places.split(">");" ?

Comment: and does case do? was that supposed to be the name for the string?

Comment: @nickfurlo String place was the name he used for the input string so I figured I might as well be consistent, and I just realized I couldn't name the variable case anyway since that's a reserved keyword. But yeah, the variable I had named case was supposed to be the name of the string representing that individual part of your trip. I just updated the variable names to make them more suitable and added comments.